# Regex makes group automatically optional?

Tags: regex

I wrote a very basic url checker.

```
((?:w{3}\.)?(?:[a-z0-9]+)(?:\.[a-z]{2,6}))
```

I want the following to be valid:

```
wwww.google.nl
google.nl
```

Right now `www.google` also gets valid which I don't want. 
It's like the regex automatically makes `(?:\.[a-z]{2,6})` group optional.

Comment: The first group is optional, you only need the last two for the pattern to succeed. `www` also matches `[a-z0-9]+`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match `wwww.google.nl`,`google.nl` and won't match `www.google`,

```
^(?:w{3}\.\w+\.[a-z]{2,6})$|^(?!www\.)\w+\.[a-z]{2,6}$
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/zZ8vG3/6)